# android actionbar oncreateoptionsmenu not called

Tags: android, android-actionbar

in my app I can see the actionbar, but I can't see the setting items, because it never call  onCreateOptionsMenu.

The app if for target sdk 16, it's composed by a tab and each tab is a fragment. 
On the Fragment class, during the onCreate() I'm calling setHasOptionsMenu(true).
The theme is Theme.Holo.Light.
If I run the app on the emulator (Android 4.0) and I press the hardware menu item, it calls the method, but it shows me the menu like the Android 2.3 menu, not in the actionbar!!

I don't think the problem is on the sdk version, because the actionbar is visible!
Any idea? what I could check to find the error?

Thanks a lot for every help!
My best regards
Manuela

Answer (score 4):

i got the same issue and solved by this way

manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

remove android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: What if i want a full screen application?

Answer (score 1):

that's the normal behaviour.
The system adapts itself to the hardware it's running on.

If the device does not have a hardware button, it shows as a drop-down from the action bar.
If the device does have a hardware button, it shows as a rise-up from near the menu button.

**edit**

If the menu is on the action bar, it's only created once (because the menus stays on the screen, does not go away like on hardware key phones), so there's another callback, I reckon it's onPrepareOptionsMenu or something similar, that one is called before the menu is shows on the screen.

Comment: If I run the app on a device (HTC OneS, there is not a menu button, only Home and Back buttons) there is the same behaviour.

Comment: I've added the overrided method onPrepareOptionsMenu() and also onOptionsItemSelected() but on the action bar I can see only the title.

Comment: A new info: if I add getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) I can see without problem the navigation button on the left of the title!